# Semantic UI submit form button outside form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, semantic-ui

I have a problem with form submitting via button outside my form. I need submit this form using this button:

`<div class="ui submit green labeled icon button">
     <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
     Create
 </div>`

But button is outside `<div id="addAcredicationForm" class="ui large form">` and not validate form. Button must be outside form in `<div class="actions">.` due footer of modal dialog.

```
<div id="addModal" class="ui small modal">
    <i class="close icon"></i>
    <div class="header">
        <div class="column">
            <h3 class="ui header">
                <i class="bordered inverted blue plus icon"></i>
                <div class="content">
                    XYZ
                </div>
            </h3>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="content">
        <div id="addAcredicationForm" class="ui large form">
            <div class="ui blue segment">
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Název akreditace</label>
                    <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="name" name="name" placeholder="aaaa">
                </div>
                <div class="field">
                    <label>Poznámka</label>
                    <textarea rows="5" maxlength="250" id="note" name="note" placeholder="bbbb"></textarea>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="ui error message"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="actions">
        <div class="ui submit green labeled icon button">
            <i class="checkmark icon"></i>
            Create
        </div>
        <div class="ui cancel red labeled icon button">
            <i class="remove icon"></i>
            Cancel
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Here is example: [jsfiddle.net/q2hLrm13/1](http://jsfiddle.net/q2hLrm13/1)

Comment: How are you intending to submit the form? There's no `<form>` tag, are you submitting via AJAX?

Comment: Here is example: http://jsfiddle.net/q2hLrm13/1/ I need to call validation function of Sematic both buttons (works only one).

Comment: In your example still there is no `form` tag. As continue of  @Starscream1984, if you intending to submit hte form using `ajax` it's not matter if the button in the form or not. If not, you have to use javascript to send the `form` when the user click on the button.

Comment: I solved it:
        function validateThis(){
            $('.form').form('validate form');
        }

            <button onclick="validateThis()" class="ui submit green labeled icon button">

Answer (score 2):

In HTML5 this is possible, you can have your submit button outside the form

```
<form id="submit-form">
...
</form>

<button type="submit" form="submit-form">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Compared to your link you can see that my button has an attribute `form="submit-form"` that tells the browser that on clicking this button, submit the form with id `submit-form`. This is a new feature in HTML5

Answer (score 1):

you can put your button anywhere, you only will need to add a class or an id on it.
Once you made your button, you can use an function like this below:

```
function pageTransition(response) {
    content.fadeOut(200, function() {
        content.html(response);
        content.fadeIn(800);
    });
}

//page transitions Get
function pageTransitionGet(url) {
    $.get(url, {}, $.noop, "html").success(pageTransition);
}

// page transitions Post
function pageTransitionPost(url, idForm) {
    $.post(url, serializeForm(idForm)).success(pageTransition);
}
function serializeForm(idForm) {    
    // Clones the form removing masks
    var formSubmit = $('#' + idForm).clone();

    // all the fields of the form
    var fieldForm = $('#' + idForm).find(':input');

    // all cloned fields
    var fieldFormSubmit = formSubmit.find(':input');

    // hidden fieldForms
    var fieldFormHidden = $('#' + idForm).find("div:hidden").find(":input");


    for (var i = 0; i < fieldForm.length; i++) {
        fieldFormSubmit[i].value = fieldForm[i].value;

        if (idForm != 'formConsultaOperacao') {
            // Bloqueia os fieldForm que estão em divs ocultas.
            if (fieldFormHidden.filter($(fieldForm[i])).exists()) {
                $(fieldFormSubmit[i]).attr("disabled", true);
            } else {
                $(fieldFormSubmit[i]).attr("disabled", false);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please edit my working example: http://jsfiddle.net/q2hLrm13/1 I need it in Semantic Form Validation.